# How can I use Microsofts WiFi Connector UWP example with WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, wifi

Edit: I have re-written the question now that the comments made clear to me what my actual question was. Somebody posted an answer, and below this answer, there was a comment that contained a link. The link pointed to a project where it was shown how to use UWP with WinForms.

---

There is a Microsoft project [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-iotcore-samples/wifi-connector/) which looks exactely like what I was looking for.

[image]

It demonstrates how to access WiFi using code.

It even supports WPS button push:

[image]

How can I use this sample with WinForms?

Comment: "_What is the reason why they presented it in UWP?_" It is normal MS tries to push their more recent desktop frameworks above the very old winforms.

Comment: What about the Native Wifi : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/nativewifi/using-the-wi-fi-direct-api?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: *"What is the reason why they presented it in UWP?"*. That's hardly a question for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinForms is an old thing and should be able to work on old OSes like win7 or even Vista. `Windows.Devices.WiFi` was introduced in Win8 (or even Win10). This is the reason it was not added directly into WinForms. But `Windows.Devices.WiFi` is just a wrapper over a native Win32 api like `WFDOpenHandle` and so on (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/nativewifi/using-the-wi-fi-direct-api?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and you can difinitely use this API in your WinForms APP with P/Invoke.

Comment: pinvoke.net can be useful for P/Invoke things, e.g. [WlanConnect (wlanapi)](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wlanapi.WlanConnect).

Comment: Wifi connectivity has nothing to do with a GUI. It's not a matter why this wasn't *added to WinForms* (??), the matter is why is not added to directly .Net Framework or .Net as a general use tool (which would be a very broad discussion) -- Even though you can use UWP APIs from WinForms or WPF.

Comment: Good note about using UWP directly without P/Invoke. I think this manual may help - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance. And yes, I agree that saying "support added into WinForms" is incorrect here and it is better to say about net/standard library/etc.